# Mongo convert all numeric fields that are stored as string

Tags: javascript, mongodb

It looks like for a while now I've been storing my decimals as strings. This is now a problem because I need to start using the aggregation framework to perform some calculations.

Is there any way to walk each document in my collection and check each value for `isNaN`, and if false, store it with `parseFloat`

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work from the mongo shell:

```
db.yourCollection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    if(isNaN(doc.xyz)) { 
        print('found string: ' + doc._id);
        db.yourCollection.update( 
           { _id: doc._id}, 
           { $set : { "xyz" : parseFloat(doc.xyz) } }
        )
    }
})
```

It loops through each document, uses `isNaN` as you suggested, then `$sets` the value to the `parseFloat` value for the current document.

Comment: As of mongodb 2.2, the update takes a query as the first param, so {_id: doc._id} instead of just doc._id.

Comment: Instead of `isNaN(doc.xyz)` you should use `typeof doc.xyz == 'string'` if your strings are "123" or "3456".

Comment: @ov1d1u - The original question however specifically asked about using `isNaN`, so I selected that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your response. I was unclear in my initial question in that I did not want to have to specify the fields to update to numbers, but rather walk each property and perform the check.

I have put together this little function to do the trick:

```
var cursor = db.results.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cursor.next();
    for (key in doc) {
        if (key.match(/^metric_.*/i) && !isNaN(doc[key])) {
            doc[key] = parseFloat(doc[key]);
            db.results.update({ _id : doc._id }, doc );
        }
    }
}
```

Two things to note:

1. This only does the check and conversion to the first level of properties. It can be easily modified to go deeper, but this was all I needed at this time.
2. **This function will blast your date values away!!!** A javascript date is evaluated by `isNaN` as false, and therefore will be treated as a number. In my case, using `parseFloat` will actually set the value to `isNaN`. Again, a very easy fix for the onlooker, but I just wanted to provide that disclaimer.

Hope this helps someone else in my position.