# MongoDB - Aggregate Sum

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am attempting to calculate the total amount of money spent being tracked inside of our database. Each order document contains a field "total_price"

I am attempting to use the following code:

```
db.orders.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        total: {$sum: "$total_price"}
    }
})
```

Unfortunately, the only output I get is: `{ "result" : [ { "_id" : null, "total" : 0 } ], "ok" : 1 }`

But to verifiy there is actually numerical data stored, and just not being totaled: `db.orders.find()[0].total_price` this results in `8.99`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have very little experience using MongoDB. I've only covered the basics at this point.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Upon more testing, it seems that integers do work, but floating point numbers do not. Is this a limitation to Mongo's Aggregate functions? If so, is there any alternatives?

Comment: Floating point should indeed work; are you sure the values in your collection are really floats and not strings? If they were strings, you would indeed see the zero result.

Comment: @drmirror I just got done discovering this, thanks for the heads up,  they are all stored as strings. Is there any way to quickly convert them to floats from within that aggregate query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861988/mongo-convert-all-numeric-fields-that-are-stored-as-string

Answer (score 7):

`$sum` only works with ints, longs and floats. Right now, there is no operator to parse a string into a number, although that would be very useful. You can do this yourself as is described in [Mongo convert all numeric fields that are stored as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861988/mongo-convert-all-numeric-fields-that-are-stored-as-string) but that would be slow.

I would suggest you make sure that your application stores numbers as int/long/float, and that you write a script that iterators over all your documents and updates the value. I would also suggest that you add a feature request at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER to add an operator that converts a string to a number.