# Mongo DB aggregate not working

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following data in a mongo collection (datacollection) :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54980efef7db7d9b018d375b"),
  "sub_id": "1234567890",
  "points": "10",
  "oid": "1",
  "name": "test",
  "app": "e53abc6d12fea63c80e4c2e1d49e",
  "source": "mysource",
  "product_name": "browser",
  "added": ISODate("2014-12-22T12:30:54.618Z"),
  "added_human": "2014-12-22 06:30:54",
  "checked": true
}
```

I actually need to find out the sum of points grouped by date. The SQL query will look like :
SELECT DATE(added) as point_date, SUM(points) AS total_points FROM mytable WHERE added between 'from' AND 'to' GROUP BY DATE(added).

So I am using the following aggregation :

```
db.datacollection.aggregate(
    { 
        $match:{
            "added" : {$gte:ISODate("2014-12-01"), $lt:ISODate("2014-12-25")},   
            "source":"mysource"  
        },   
        $group : {
            "_id" : { month: { $month: "$added" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$added" }, year: { $year: "$added" } },
            "total_points":{$sum:"$points"}   
        }  
    }  
);
```

But this is showing

```
"errmsg" : "exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.",
```

How this can be fixed or is there any better method for doing this calculation ??

Comment: I think you should change your `points` data type string to integer or float.

Comment: yeah. But how can I do this on the fly ?

Comment: you don't changed data type on the fly, first you should update your collections as proper data type and then used mongo aggregation. For your reference check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138750/mongodb-aggregate-sum

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this:

```
db.datacollection.aggregate(
    { 
        $match:{
            "added" : {$gte:ISODate("2014-12-01"), $lt:ISODate("2014-12-25")},   
            "source":"mysource"  
        }
    },   
    {   $group : {
            "_id" : { month: { $month: "$added" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$added" }, year: { $year: "$added" } },
            "total_points":{$sum:"$points"}   
        }  
    }  
);
```

You should use this format (every pipeline in in `{}` pair)

```
db.collection.aggrgation ( 
   { $group: ....},
   { $match : .... },
   ...
})
```

but you used:

```
db.collection.aggrgation ( 
   { $group: ....,
     $match : ....,
     ...
   }
})
```

Comment: This is showing me the result like total_points as 0.it is not taking the SUM. I need to type convert the value ?

Comment: but i got the result with your sample doc. result : {
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 12,
                "day" : 22,
                "year" : 2014
            },
            "total_points" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}

Comment: yeah . I am also getting total_points as zero. I need to get 10 as the points value is 10. Or if there is other records, it should show the total sum

Comment: because your points is string not int, change it from **"10"** to **10** and you will get your answer

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate operand needs to be inside the group {}