# Mongodb Aggregation Query with $sum

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called `test`. I want to get total amount of one key: `sal` across all documents present in the `test` collection.

Here is sample document:

```
[
    {
    "name": "hari",
    "sal": "100",
    "status": "Y",
    "address": "Bangalore"
    },
    {
    "name": "Sam",
    "sal": "200",
    "status": "Y",
    "address": "Bangalore"
    },
    {
    "name": "Nik",
    "sal": "200",
    "status": "N",
    "address": "Bangalore"
    }
]
```

and I tried the following query:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{
  $match: {
    Status: "Y"
  }
}, {
$group: {
    _id: null,
    total: {
        $sum: "$sal"
    }
  }
}])
```

I am getting zero.

Can anyone suggest me the right query to add a particular key across all the documents in a collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to aggregate sum in MongoDB to get a total count?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044587/how-to-aggregate-sum-in-mongodb-to-get-a-total-count)

Comment: It would sound like your `sal` field is actually a string, or at least not a number, or non-existant.

Comment: Your query looks correct at first glance but it might not fit your documents. Please post an example document.

Comment: Hi Philipp, The below are some sample document of test collections  *******   test
{ 
"name": "hari",
"sal":"100",
"status": "Y",
"address": "Bangalore"
}

{ 
"name": "Sam",
"sal":"200",
"status": "Y",
"address": "Bangalore"
}

{ 
"name": "Nik",
"sal":"200",
"status": "N",
"address": "Bangalore"
}  while run the aggregation query db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{$match:{status:"Y"}},{$group:{_id:null,total:{$sum:"$sal"}}}]). I am getting zero value.

Comment: As per your document structure `sal` looks like `string` data type, so either you should changed `sal` data type to `Int or Float` for more how to convert data type check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498872/how-to-change-datatype-of-netsted-field-in-mongo-document)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the sample document,

`$sum` only works with ints, longs and floats. Right now, there is no operator to parse a string into a number, although that would be very useful. You can do this yourself as is described in Mongo convert all numeric fields that are stored as string [Mongo convert all numeric fields that are stored as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861988/mongo-convert-all-numeric-fields-that-are-stored-as-string)

You can refer the below answer for further details:-
[MongoDB - Aggregate Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138750/mongodb-aggregate-sum)

Comment: Use this totalAmount: 
$group:
         {
           totalAmount: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$sal", "$quantity" ] } }
          
         }

Comment: $multiply only supports numeric types, not String